# Is it true that a measure zero set must be nowhere dense?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know that a meager set could be dense or nowhere dense; a meager set is not necessarily measure zero; and a measure zero set is not necessarily meager.

Comment: I don't get it. You know that a measure zero set is not necessarily meager, but you are asking whether a measure zero set must be nowhere dense? Does that mean you don't know that nowhere dense sets are meager? What is your definition of meager set?

Comment: @bof I believe a meager set (countable union of nowhere dense set) could be dense?

Comment: Yes, a meager set can be dense. So what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}$ has measure zero and is already dense.

Answer (score 4):

As you said in your post, "a measure zero set is not necessarily meager". I.e., there is a measure zero set $A$ which is not meager.

But every nowhere dense set is meager ("countable union of nowhere dense sets").

Since $A$ is not meager, it follows that $A$ is not nowhere dense.

The set $A$ has measure zero, but $A$ is not nowhere dense.

It is not true that a measure zero set must be nowhere dense.

Answer (score 1):

There are no implications between measure zero and meagre. You can write the reals as a union of a measure zero set $A$ and a meagre set $B$. So the measure zero one cannot be meagre and the meagre set cannot have measure zero.

Comment: A really great little book on the relationship between measure and Baire category is Oxtoby's *Measure and Category*

Comment: It was already stated in the original question that " a meager set is not necessarily measure zero; and a measure zero set is not necessarily meager."